# Incomplete Gamma Asymptotics

Tags: asymptotics, special-functions

my question is simple : if $a_n$ and $z_n$ are both real positive sequences tending to $+\infty$, what is the asymptotic ($n \to +\infty$) behaviour of $\Gamma(a_n,z_n)$ when 1) $a_n \neq z_n$ and $\frac{a_n}{z_n} \to 1$ and 2) $a_n << z_n$ ?

Thanks :)

Comment: when $x \to \infty$, everything depends on  $M(x)$ the $t$ where $t^{x-1} e^{-t}$ is maximum. for example if $a_n < M(z_n) / 2$ then clearly $\Gamma(a_n,z_n) \sim \Gamma(z_n)$

Comment: If $a_n$ were fixed, then you would use Laplace's method for endpoints to get the asymptotic. Since $a_n$ is growing, it could happen that you need to use Laplace's method for critical points instead. Indeed the maximum of $t^{z-1} e^{-t}$ is at the solution to $(z-1)t^{z-2} - t^{z-1}=0$ i.e. at $t=z-1$. So it all depends on how $a_n$ compares to $z_n-1$. Being more specific it looks like the problem with $a_n/z_n \to 1$ is not well-defined by itself, you need sharper information to derive the asymptotic in that case.

Comment: Thank you for the answers. I would like also to know if i can use some asymptotic expansion in the case where $a_n,z_n \to +\infty$ and $\frac{a_n}{z_n} \to 0$.